# Hidden layers within sequential layer after importing model in Keras

Tags: import, keras

i have a "simple" problem after loading Keras model.

During training my network has following structure

```
model.summary()
```

[Output from command line after defining architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clmli.png)

After training + saving + loading my network appears to have following structure:

[Output from command line after loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgdDR.png)

Unfortunately I'm unable to find the way to access the sequential layer. My goal is to visualize the feature maps which are within the sequential layer.

I will provide code in case it will be necessary.

Thank you,
Vaclav